# Mxml and as3 confusion [simple]

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I was wondering i can call an as3 function defined in script from mxml code just like this:

```
<mx:Line x="translateX(xmin);" .. >


<mx:Script>
   <![CDATA[

   // do some basic math
   private function translate ...
```

If not possible do i have to convert everything to as3 ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Please specify what you mean by "if not possible".

Answer (score 5):

You can but a straight-up function call like that needs to go into an event attribute in MXML, i.e. "when this event is dispatched, invoke this function."  The classic example being:

```
<mx:Button label="Hello" click="myFunction()"/>
```

You can use a function as you have illustrated above provided that it's in a binding expression and the arguments passed to the function are bindable:

```
<mx:Line x="{positionLine(xmin)}"/>

// defined somewhere in a mx:Script block
[Bindable] private var xmin : Number;
```